# How to ask an 'immature' question without reprecussions

Tags: discussion

I have a very inappropriate, somewhat immature claim that I want to have verified on this stack. However, even though I am very serious about it, I am worried that it will not be taken seriously, and at worst, people will think I'm a troll. I have done multiple searches on my question, and nothing has yielded a definite answer.

How do I ask a question about an immature claim on a NSFW subject and have stackers take me seriously?

Comment: you can ask the mods in a private chat room if you want

Comment: @Sklivvz ask it it's okay to post, or the question itself?

Comment: ask for help on how to post it so it's well received

Comment: Alright I've created a temporary gallery room for mods too met with me for this question..